# adding a .where to check items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am currently getting a list of types depending on the dropdown of the page. My issue is that i need to check in the controller if the item is active or not before displaying in the dropdown list.

My current code in my controller to get the list is:

```
viewModel.AvailableSongTypes = viewModel.songTypeId.HasValue
            ? _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems(viewModel.SongTypeId.ToString())
            : _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems();
```

I want to add

```
.Where(a=>a.IsActive ?? false)
```

but not sure how to add it to the lines of code i already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone Thank You for all your help! I was able to think around it and rewrite how my list is being made which then i was able to add my .where phrase. This is what i changed it to:

```
viewModel.AvailableSongTypes =
            _songTypeRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(o => o.Description).Where(a => a.IsActive).ToSelectList(
                "SongTypeId", "Description", viewModel.SongTypeId.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
viewModel.AvailableSongTypes = viewModel.songTypeId.HasValue 
        ? _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems(viewModel.SongTypeId.ToString()).Where(a=>a.IsActive ?? false) 
        : _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems().Where(a=>a.IsActive ?? false);
```

Or

```
viewModel.AvailableSongTypes = (viewModel.songTypeId.HasValue 
        ? _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems(viewModel.SongTypeId.ToString())
        : _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems()).Where(a=>a.IsActive ?? false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
viewModel.AvailableSongTypes = viewModel.songTypeId.HasValue
            ? _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems(viewModel.SongTypeId.ToString()).Where(a => a.IsActive ?? false)
            : _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems().Where(a => a.IsActive ?? false);
```

Or the best one:

```
viewModel.AvailableSongTypes = (viewModel.songTypeId.HasValue
            ? _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems(viewModel.SongTypeId.ToString())
            : _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems()).Where(a => a.IsActive ?? false);
```

Comment: I tried the second one you have but it is coloring IsActive as red and saying that it cannot resolve it. I think i might need to change how the whole list is created so i can check with the songsType entity to refer to the isActive object.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you're looking for (I'm not at a machine with Visual Studio at the moment, so I can't be 100% sure it'll compile cleanly):

```
Func<SongTypeItem,bool> isActive = i => i.IsActive ?? false;

viewModel.AvailableSongTypes = viewModel.songTypeId.HasValue
  ? _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems(viewModel.SongTypeId.ToString()).Where(isActive)
  : _songTypeService.GetSongTypeItems().Where(isActive);
```

What you're basically doing is filtering your enumerable sequence of "song type items" with the `Where` extension method.  The creation of the `Func` `isActive` is just to keep from repeating myself - you could inline it right in the `Where` call.